# filtrar datatable por rango de fechas

Tags: javascript, datatables, date, datepicker

tengo este datatable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Date_search").val("");
});

var table = $('#tabla').DataTable( {
  deferRender:    true, 
  "autoWidth": false,     
  "search": {
    "regex": true,
    "caseInsensitive": false,
  },});

$('#Date_search').on( 'keyup change', function () {
  table.draw();
});

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = $("#Date_search").val().split(" to ")[0];
    var max = $("#Date_search").val().split(" to ")[1];
    var date = data[2] || ""; // use data for the date column
    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
        ( isNaN( min ) && date <= max ) ||
        ( min <= date   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
        ( min <= date   && date <= max ) )
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);

$("#Date_search").daterangepicker({
  "locale": {
    "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "separator": " to ",
    "applyLabel": "Apply",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
    "fromLabel": "From",
    "toLabel": "To",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "weekLabel": "W",
    "daysOfWeek": [
      "Su",
      "Mo",
      "Tu",
      "We",
      "Th",
      "Fr",
      "Sa"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1
  },
  "opens": "center",
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    Date: <input id="Date_search" type="text" placeholder="Search by Date" /><br>        
    <table id='tabla'>
      <thead>
        <td>Date</td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-05-05</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-05-06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-05-07</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-05-08</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-05-09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2018-05-10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y no consigo que me filtre correctamente por las fechas.

He seguido la documentación de DataTable para el filtrado de un rango de fechas y no encuentro lo que me está fallando.

He buscado en stackoverflow y en internet y no encuentro ninguna solución a mi problema.

¿Alguna idea para hacer que funcione?

Gracias

(Por si tenéis que trastear: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBZjZZ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He cambiado tu código para que filtre por fechas:

```
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Date_search").val("");
});

var table = $('#tabla').DataTable( {
  deferRender:    true, 
  "autoWidth": false,     
  "search": {
    "regex": true,
    "caseInsensitive": false,
  },});

$("#Date_search").daterangepicker({
  "locale": {
    "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "separator": " to ",
    "applyLabel": "Apply",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
    "fromLabel": "From",
    "toLabel": "To",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "weekLabel": "W",
    "daysOfWeek": [
      "Su",
      "Mo",
      "Tu",
      "We",
      "Th",
      "Fr",
      "Sa"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1
  },
  "opens": "center",
}, function(start, end, label) {
  maxDateFilter = end;
  minDateFilter = start;
  table.draw();  
});
```

Lo que he hecho ha sido añadir la función de filtrado por fechas a datatables, y luego en el callback del daterangepicker guardar en las variables globales las fechas de start y end.

Esto lo he encontrado en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38718922/4435962)
Y tienes el ejemplo [aqui](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrKVmN)